# Mvc3 cannot bind parameter in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a simple jQuery ajax method:

```
        var sendData = { personId: "@(Guid.Empty)"};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("Dialog", "Dialog")",
            data: sendData;
        }).done(function (e) {
            $('#dialog').html(e);
            window.resizeDialog();
        });
```

In the dialogController:

```
    public ActionResult PersonInfo(Guid personId)
    {
         ....
    }
```

jQuery will pass a personId as Guid to the controller and the controller will do it's stuff and return a PartialView as dialog.

This works fine and is being used quite alot in a few big project with numerous users.

But rarely (around 1 per 10.000 hits) I get this exception by our logger:

```
22-8-2012 14:17:27 ERROR: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'personId' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PersonInfo(System.Guid)' in 'Site.Controllers.DialogController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters at System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

What I tried was changing the DataType of the $.ajax method, but it didn't help. Now I found out that MOST (not all) errors come from IE8 (90%).

What could be wrong here and how can I prevent this? For some methods I made all arguments nullable and I will check for null later in the method, but this is not optimal because the request will fail.

Comment: What logger are you using? Try plugging in Elmah and capture all request so you can see what your controller is receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is more likely a problem with the data your sending up. I noticed you are posting the JSON object "raw" (without any type of parsing) which could be where the problem is. Try using [JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a 3rd party library like [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) (cross browser) and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: Where do you see manual JSON string generation? There's none.

Comment: var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ userSquadId: '@(Model.UserSquadId)', personId1: personId1, personId2: personId2, oldSlot: oldSlot, newSlot: newSlot, position: pos, fromBench: fromBench, toBench: toBench });

This is one that I use, I was already using JSON.stringify.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I probably didn't word that correct, what I was referring to was the JSON object being created & sent up "raw" without being parsed etc. @Rogier21 your sample didn't mention you were using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev `sendData` is the JSON object, if you want to be pedantic about it technically it's a javascript object, but as it's being passed as the `data` parameter of the `post` request it is essentially a JSON object.

Comment: @James No, it's not. It will be sent as HTML form POST notation (`personId=FBCFDFF5-2F4F-4FD6-8FCF-DC0C84EAEE2B&personName=Smith&age=13`), not JSON.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev Your correct, that was my confusion - just read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to quote your string, so your result javascript looks like:

```
var sendData = { personId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000};
```

which will either result in `0` or don't work at all. Try following:

```
var sendData = { personId: "@(Guid.Empty)"};
```

Comment: Ok fair enough, but this is a code sample, ofcourse i won't be sending empty guid

Comment: @Rogier21 then it depends on what and how you're sending it. We can't make guesses on code that does not match problem.